# Ansible: Get instance_ids from multiple stacks

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm trying to get a list of instance_ids from different stacks:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    stack_names:
      - 'stacka'
      - 'stackb'
      - 'stackc'

  tasks:
  - name: "get cloudformation facts from stacks"
    cloudformation_facts:
      stack_name: "{{ item }}"
      stack_resources: true
    with_items: "{{ stack_names }}"
    register: cf_tmp

  - name: "Get list of instance_ids"
    set_fact:
      instance_ids: "{{ dict(cf_tmp.results | map(attribute=ansible_facts['cloudformation'][stack_name]['stack_resources']['instance'])) }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ instance_ids }}"
```

but got the following error:

```
TASK [Get list of instance_ids] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'stack_name' is undefined
```

Anyway to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see `stack_name` defined anywhere in your example (as reported by your error message). Did you mean `'stack_name'`? Moreover, the entire attribute name should be quoted in your expression. Since not everyone has access to cloudfotmatiin to test, you should give an example of the registers facts and of the exact expected result.

Comment: @jackw11111, changing to cloudformation_facts results in similar error, instead of 'stack_name', it's `The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'cloudformation'.  Seems like both are for single stack.

Comment: Your example may need a `stack_name`, [see this documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/cloudformation_module.html#options) says `stack_name` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using role as workaround to get the job done.

```
#role
  - name: "get cloudformation facts from stacks"
    cloudformation_info:
      stack_name: "{{ stack_name }}"
      stack_resources: true
    register: cf_tmp

  - name: get instance id from stack
    set_fact:
      instance_id: "{{ cf_tmp.cloudformation[stack_name].stack_resources.Instance }}"
```

```
roles:
    - role: GetInstanceId
      vars:
        stack_name: "stacka"

    - role: GetInstanceId
      vars:
        stack_name: "stackb"

    - role: GetInstanceId
      vars:
        stack_name: "stackc"
```